# How do I retain blank results when no data has been found instead of #N/A on =FILTER ? (Example Google Sheet attached)

Tags: google-sheets, filter, calendar, google-sheets-formula, formula

I'm making a Dynamic Calendar to organize amongst a small group, I've gotten it set up exactly how I want & the formula works - I just want the #N/A results to show as a blank cell themself when referencing a blank cell from the second Sheet - I've tried a variety of =IFNA within the formula so far, but I just know I'm missing something.

The Google Doc below is just the bare bones of it, I don't want to change the layout or where things are set (*if I can avoid it*) however I'm open to suggestions - I hope one of you can help me with this!

I know this is probably a very simple fix, I'm just very tired from making sheet after sheet.

(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nbbr9BMmFJ785j5wqE0yLLNYZcItOrYyOdebcSWkFaY/edit?usp=sharing)

I've tried including a variety of =IFNA within the formula, but I think I'm just mentally fried on it.

I'm close to just making it all black to mask the #N/a ;_;

Comment: you could go with `=ifna(<your filter formula>)` OR `=iferror(<your filter formula>)`. Also you may want to check on the output in *Cell_B7* as its supposed to have 2 results (Test 1, Test 11) & is currently throwing a *#REF* error as it cant expand into *Cell_B8* (since its already populated by formula). wrapping such scenarios with `iferror` will neither populate Test 1 OR Test 11 and will end up blank!

Comment: Oh the REF formula is just me having a mini rage at it - I'll try your suggestion once I get home and will add another comment based on it's result; thank you in advance!! :)

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!! <3 (I used the =IFERROR(<formula>) with nothing else added ^^

Comment: When your filter formula has an ***output that has more than one row of data*** (explained with an example in 1st comment here); the setup you have here in the sheet will force it throw a #REF error. Using an `iferror` for such scenarios will cover up the #REF error with a blank output although there's a valid output for it.